# Is the Reference Speed (Vref) the same as the speed at which the aircraft cross the runway threshold in landing phase?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-physics

Just a little confuse when I learned about the aircraft classification based on approach speed. Can anyone help me to have an accuracy look about this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V<sub>ref</sub> is indeed defined as

> Landing reference speed or threshold crossing speed.

It is normally set with reference to V<sub>s<sub>0</sub></sub> which is stall speed in landing configuration. V<sub>ref</sub> must usually be greater than 1.3x V<sub>s<sub>0</sub></sub>.

By way of example, the POH for my PA-28 lists the stall speed with flaps down (ie. landing configuration) as 45KIAS. I tend to be around 70KIAS on final approach and 65KIAS over the threshold. 1.3x my stall speed would be roughly 59KIAS, so I have about 5KIAS safety.

Comment: For an airliner, the target for the threshold crossing speed is typically 5 to 15 knots higher than $v_\text{ref}$, depending on headwind.

Comment: @Bianfable It surprises me that its not represented still as a factor of vref

Comment: Since it's related to wind, I guess they add because the wind speed is additive to the airspeed, but not sure. Airbus has a [lengthy article](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/control-your-speed-during-descent-approach-and-landing/) on the topic (search for "Lowest Selectable Speed" and "Approach speed" for the relevant parts).